# How to change settings or preferences in firefox source code?

Tags: firefox, mozilla

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2Muh.png)I have built Firefox using MozillaBuild but I want the change the default settings or preferences, for example the homepage or more preferences page. I want to do this directly from the code. Although I don't want to use autoconfig because it requires it to be in the root of the directory. Here's some images.

I have tried searching the web and checking the source code but to no avail :(